# Dimension of an irreducible representation and index of the center

Tags: representation-theory

G is a finite group of order n, Z(G) is its center of order 'k'. I want to show that if V is an irreducible complex representation of G, then dim(V) $\leq$ $\sqrt{\frac{n}{k}}$.

I noted that Z(G) is an abelian subgroup of G and with a little effort was able to arrive that dim(V) $\leq$ [G : Z(G)] = $\frac{n}{k}$. However, I don't see a way to get to the actual result. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: I fixed the question. Thank you. I remember that sum of squares of dimensions of irreducible representations must be equal to the order of the group but I am not arriving at any obvious conclusion..

Comment: So far I have reached a conclusion that at least one of such irreducible representation must have dimension less than or equal to $\frac{n}{k}$, using the fact that number of conjugacy classes is at least equal to the order of the center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\rho : G \to GL(V)$ be a complex irreducible representation. Extending this, we obtain an algebra morphism $\rho : \mathbb{C}G \to \text{End}_\mathbb{C}(V)$. Now you can proceed by showing the following:

1. The algebra morphism $\rho$ is surjective (this is a consequence of the Artin-Wedderburn theorem, since $\mathbb{C}G$ is semisimple). In particular, 
   $$\dim(\mathbb{C}G/\ker(\rho)) \geq \dim(\text{End}_\mathbb{C}(V)) = \dim(V)^2$$
2. The elements of $Z(G)$ act on $V$ as scalars (by Schur's Lemma).
   In particular $\{\lambda(z) - z \:|\: z \in Z(G)\}$ is contained 
   in $\ker(\rho)$ for some $\lambda : Z(G) \to \mathbb{C}^*$.
3. The quotient $\mathbb{C}G/\ker(\rho)$ is generated by the cosets of $Z(G)$ in $G$ and so $$\dim(\mathbb{C}G/\ker(\rho)) \leq n/k.$$

Putting the inequalities in 1. and 3. together yields the result.

Comment: In our course, Artin-Wedderburn Theorem is not covered, although everything else makes sense to me. So I am gonna try to see a proof of Artin-Wedderburn Theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another method using the [tensor power trick](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/08/25/tricks-wiki-article-the-tensor-product-trick/), based on an argument of Tate.

By Schur's lemma, each element $z \in Z(G)$ acts on $V$ by a scalar $\lambda_z \in \mathbb{C}$. Assume for the moment that $Z(G)$ acts trivially on $V$, i.e. $\lambda_z = 1$ for all $z \in Z(G)$. Then $V$ is an an irrep of the quotient group $G/Z(G)$. Since the size of a finite group equals the sum of squares of the dimensions of its irreps, we conclude that $\dim(V)^2 \le |G|/|Z(G)|$, as desired.

While it may not be the case that $Z(G)$ acts trivially on $V$, we can modify the above strategy by passing to the tensor power $V^{\otimes n}$, which is an irrep of $G^n$. An element $(z_1, \ldots, z_n) \in Z(G)^n$ acts on $V^{\otimes n}$ by multiplication by $\lambda_{z_1} \cdots \lambda_{z_n}$. Therefore, the normal subgroup $$ H_n := \{(z_1, \ldots, z_n) \in Z(G)^n \mid z_1 \cdots z_n = 1\} $$ acts trivially on $V^{\otimes n}$. Thus, $V^{\otimes n}$ is an irrep of the quotient group $G^n/H_n$. We conclude that $$\dim(V)^{2n} = \dim(V^{\otimes n})^2 \le |G^n/H_n| = \frac{|G|^n}{|Z(G)|^{n - 1}}.$$ Taking $n$th roots and sending $n \to \infty$, we conclude that $\dim(V)^2 \le |G|/|Z(G)|$.